# Overwriting text files output

Tags: python

Gd day fellow pros,

I want to overwrite my file with the result I have gotten but stuck with the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'`

**current code**

```py
path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder\1'
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files: #read all files in path folder
    full_path = open(path + "\\" + f,"r") #join path + file name
    full_path_read = full_path.read() #read file
    res = '\n'.join(full_path_read[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(full_path_read), 8)) #break sentence every 8th character
    f.write(res) #overwrite file with result
    f.close()
```

**edited solution (it works :) )**

```py
path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder\1'
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    full_path = open(path + "\\" + f,"r")
    full_path_read = full_path.read()
    res = '\n'.join(full_path_read[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(full_path_read), 8))
    full_path.close()
    f = open(path + "\\" + f,"w")
    f.write(res)
    f.close()
```

Comment: `f` contains the filename and is a string. Do you want to write to that file? Then you may want to close `full_path` and open it again in write mode

Comment: You should open file with the name in variable f

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `full_path` doesn't actually contain the full path; instead, it contains a file handle opened for reading.

A simple fix is to change the code so that `full_path` actually contains the full path, then open the file again for writing, then write.

```py
path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder\1'

for f in os.listdir(path):
    full_path = os.path.join(path, f)
    with open(full_path, "r") as readhandle:
        full_path_read = readhandle.read()
    res = '\n'.join(full_path_read[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(full_path_read), 8))
    with open(full_path, "w") as writehandle:
        writehandle.write(res)
```

Notice also how with `with open` you don't need to explicitly `close()` the file.

However, if the file is big, perhaps a better solution would be to read one line at a time, and just keep track of how many characters to keep in the first segment from the previous line.  Then you can use [the `fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) in its `inplace=True` mode and not explicitly write anything back.

Answer (score 0):

The use of os.path.join() is unnecessary in this particular case as the path is known to be in Windows style. Therefore, I suggest this (note the mode used to open the files:-

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder\1'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path + '\\' + file, 'r+') as iofile:
        data = iofile.read()
        iofile.seek(0)
        res = '\n'.join(data[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(data), 8))
        iofile.write(res)
```